# Python video plays and hangs after 1 second with socket program

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to write a python socket program which will do the following:

1. A server program starts and plays a video
2. The timestamp of the video is sent continuously to a socket
3. On the client side, the client will get the value of the timestamp from the socket message

**Server Code:**

```
    import cv2
    import socket

    s = socket.socket()
    print ("Socket successfully created")
    port = 12345
    
    cap=cv2.VideoCapture("D:/video.mp4")
    if cap.isOpened()==False:
        print("Error opening")

    s.bind(('', port))
    print ("socket bound to %s" %(port))
    s.setblocking(1)
    s.listen(5)
    print ("socket is listening")
    try:
        while cap.isOpened():
            ret,frame=cap.read()

            if ret==True:
                cv2.imshow("Frame",frame)
                while True:
                    c, addr = s.accept()
                    print ('Got connection from', addr )
                    c.sendall(str(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)).encode("utf=8"))
            else:
                cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,0)
                continue
            c.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    cap.release()
```

**Client Code:**

```
# Import socket module
import socket

# Create a socket object
s = socket.socket()

# Define the port on which you want to connect
port = 12345

# connect to the server on local computer
s.connect(('localhost', port))

# receive data from the server and decoding to get the string.
print (s.recv(16).decode())
# close the connection
s.close()
```

When running this code, the video starts and then hangs immediately. Running the client program gives the output **1.0** . Running it multiple times always gives the same output.

I am new to socket programming and my guess is that this is due to the blocking nature of the sockets. However, setting s.setblocking(0) results in an exception

```
BlockingIOError: [WinError 10035] A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately
```

Without any of the socket code, the video runs fine and I can **print** the timestamp to the console.

How do I fix the issue? Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: more focus please. your problem is either sockets *or* opencv, not both. I've removed the OpenCV tag for you. -- did you even debug the program? did you notice the `while True: c, addr = s.accept()`? please review [mre]. you must learn debugging. and please find resources to learn how sockets are supposed to be used.

Comment: you have to run `opencv` and `socket` in separated threads. `accept()` blocks code because it waits for client. And you should run `accept()` before `while`-loop because current code needs new connection to send new image. And code will have another problem - `socket` is very primitive and it may send data splited in many packages or send many images connected in one package and client will have to run loop to get all data - but socket doesn't inform where is end of every frame so client will not know which part display as first frame and which as second frame.

Comment: you will have to add code which will add this information. And both sides will have to respect these information. Server may first send size of data (as 4 bytes) and next data. And client will have to first read 4 bytes to get data size and later use this size in `recv()`. And all these rules are called "protocol" (similar to `HTTP` - `HyperText Transport Protocol`, `FTP` - `File Transfer Protocol`, `SMTP` - `Send Mail Transfer Protocol`, etc.).

Comment: I see another problem. `imshow()` needs `waitKey` to correctly display image in window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`accept()` blocks code because it waits for client.
So you have to run `opencv` or `socket` in separated threads. And you will have to send data to client in separated thread.

You should run `accept()` before `while`-loop because current code needs new connection to send new data to the same client.

Your code will have another problem. `socket` is very primitive and it may send data splitted into many parts - and client will have to run loop to get all data - or it may send many packages connected in one package - and client will have to crop data to correct size. But socket doesn't inform where is end of every data so client will not know which part display as first timestamp and which as next timestamp. You may have to send always string with the same size - and client will have to get always string with the same size. Or it would need to send size before data (and size would be data with constant size) and client would have to first get size and later use it to get correct data.

**client.py**

```
import socket

PORT = 12345

s = socket.socket()
s.connect(('', PORT))

buffer = ""
while True:
    buffer += s.recv(20).decode()
    if len(buffer) >= 20:   # server sends every timestamp as 20 chars
        text = buffer[:20]
        print(text, end='\r')
        buffer = buffer[20:]

s.close()
```

**server.py**

```
import cv2
import socket
import threading

def player():
    global timestamp
    
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("D:/video.mp4")
    #cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # local webcam - but it has timestamp `-1.0`
    if not cap.isOpened():
        print("Error opening")

    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if ret:
            cv2.imshow("Frame",frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == 27:  # key ESC
                break
            timestamp = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
        else:
            cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)
            timestamp = 0

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cap.release()

def process_client(c, addr):
   
    # run loop to send it continuously
    try:
        while True:
            text = f'{timestamp:20}'  # create string always with 20 chars
            c.sendall(text.encode("utf-8"))
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Exception:', ex)
        
    c.close()
    
def server():

    PORT = 12345
    
    threads = []
    
    s = socket.socket()
    print("Socket successfully created")
    
    s.bind(('', PORT))
    print(f"socket bound to {PORT}")
    
    #s.setblocking(True)
    s.listen(5)
    print("socket is listening")
    
    try:
        while True:
            print('Waiting for next client ...')
            c, addr = s.accept()
            print('Got connection from', addr)
            
            # process every client in separated thread
            t = threading.Thread(target=process_client, args=(c, addr))
            t.start()
            
            threads.append([c, addr, t])
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Exception:', ex)
        
    for c, addr, t in threads:
        c.close()
        
    s.close()
    
# --- main ---

timestamp = 0

# run server in separated thread
t = threading.Thread(target=server)
t.start()

player()
```

---

**BTW:**

`HTTP` uses other method to send headers with unknown size before data. It sends empty line at the end of headers - two new lines `\n\n` - and client checks if buffer has two `\n\n` to crop data in this places.

Comment: I think it may need extra code when it closes threads and sockets. i.e. it may need to check if threads is still running `t.is_alive()`. And it may need code to stop server when you close player.